# Abrir enlace en una nueva ventana del navegador

Tags: html, python, django

Estoy desarrollando una aplición web en django donde tengo un formulario con un select. Si el usuario no encuentra el elemento en la lista, este puede agregarlo pulsando un link y quiero que me salga en una nueva pestaña al igual que en los formulario del admin cuando quieres agregar un nuevo elemento en un select de un ForeigthKey y luego te redirecciona al formulario de inicio.

Alguien puede ayudarme en este sentido??

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0):

Esto es html y debes agregar `target="_blank"`  no mas dale bro

Ejemplo:

```
<a href="https://www.w3schools.com" target="_blank">Visit W3Schools</a>
```